# Way to slim down this if..else statement even more?

Tags: php, syntax

```
$specify_step = ($_GET['specify_step']) ? $_GET['specify_step'] : getNextStep($returnId,$type);
```

Given the above statement, is there a way to shorthand this if statement even more so that I don't have to say $_GET['specify_step'] twice?

In the cases when I'm accessing GET or COOKIES etc, it always seems redundant and "wordier" then it needs to be.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but does `$_GET['specify_step']` return a boolean?

Comment: I think if it returns anything, it will be treated as true and otherwise it will be treated as false.

Comment: @Nik Either empty or `0` will evaluate to `false`. See [docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$specify_step = ($_GET['specify_step']) ?: getNextStep($returnId,$type);
```

It made enough logical sense to me that I had to go look it up....and [according to php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), it works in PHP 5.3. If you're using 5.3, you're in luck.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it gets much more compact than that. My only thought is to make a temporary variable to hold `$_GET['specify_step']`, but that doesn't seem any shorter.

Answer (score 0):

**As I mentioned in a comment to your question, I don't know PHP.**

Check if this works. In most langauages, if the first part is true, the function `getNextStep` won't be called.

```
$specify_step = ($_GET['specify_step']) || getNextStep($returnId,$type);
```

Comment: That should not work - the PHP documentation specifies that the logical-or operator returns a boolean, not its argument (obviously, assuming the ‘specify_step‘ isn't a boolean).

Comment: @Andrew Medico Apologies, should I strike the answer? Since I mentioned *most languages* it might help someone looking for similar thing...

Answer (score 0):

There would be this alternate boolean evaluation approach, but it just goes to show that you have to duplicate *something*:

```
 $specify_step = $_GET['specify_step']
 or
 $specify_step = getNextStep($returnId,$type);
```

(Also works without decorative linebreaks.)

With PHP 5.3 you *might* of course use the `?:` shortcut. If that's available.

Personally I can alternate to `$_GET->default('specify_step', 123)` for such cases.